# Custom magic in ipython notebooks - Code does not execute

Tags: python, ipython

I am relatively new to ipython magics and want to run some code and at the same time add it to a list through the magic commands. The magics are defined as follows

```
#iPython notebook magic
from IPython.core.magic import  (
    Magics, magics_class, cell_magic, line_magic
)

@magics_class
class ReportMagic(Magics):
    def __init__(self, shell,  data):
        super(ReportMagic,self).__init__(shell)
        self._code_store = []
        self._markdown_store = []
        self._conf_code_store=[]
        self._conf_markdown_store=[]
        self.data = data
        # inject our store in user availlable namespace under __mystore
        # name
        shell.user_ns['__mycodestore'] = self._code_store
        shell.user_ns['__mymarkdownstore'] = self._markdown_store

    @cell_magic
    def add_code_to_report(self, line, cell):
        """store the cell in the store"""
        self._code_store.append(cell)

    @cell_magic
    def add_markdown_to_report(self, line, cell):
        """store the cell in the store"""
        self._markdown_store.append(cell)

    @cell_magic
    def add_conf_code_to_report(self, line, cell):
        """store the cell in the store"""
        self._conf_code_store.append(cell)

    @cell_magic
    def add_conf_markdown_to_report(self, line, cell):
        """store the cell in the store"""
        self._conf_markdown_store.append(cell)


    @line_magic
    def show_report(self, line):
        """show all recorded statements"""
        return self._conf_markdown_store,self._conf_code_store ,self._markdown_store,self._code_store

# This class must then be registered with a manually created instance,
# since its constructor has different arguments from the default:
ip = get_ipython()
magics = ReportMagic(ip, 0)
ip.register_magics(magics)
```

and I am calling the magics as follows

```
%%add_conf_code_to_report

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import collections
```

The import code is copied to the _conf_code_store alright but I cannot call the functions from the imported libraries.
I want that the code should be added to the _conf_code_store and at the same time the imported libaries' functionality should be available in the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to get a work around it.
To execute a code through the magic function one has to call run_cell instance for the ipython object. There can be better ways of doing it but the code works for now.

```
@cell_magic
@needs_local_scope
def add_conf_code_to_report(self, line, cell):
    """store the cell in the store"""
    self._conf_code_store.append(cell)
    print type(cell)
    exec 'from IPython.core.display import HTML'
    for each in cell.split('\n'):
        print each
        exec repr(each.strip())
    ip=get_ipython()
    ip.run_cell(cell)
```